# What is underneath ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am familiar with server technologies like ExpressJS and Flask. On the other hand I clearly understood the underlying concepts of CGI and Servlet. Flask/Django further extends CGI to WSGI and uses it. And, Servlet is so widely used in Java frameworks. Now, what is underneath ExpressJS/NodeJS ? I am completely blind and I don't even know if this is relevant.

Please correct if my question is idiotic. I am unable to inter relate these technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressJS uses the built-in nodejs http/https modules as its http server. Your express instance is an http server by itself.

It does not work like Apache or CGI where there's an http server somewhere else that is forwarding you certain requests or in the case of CGI, it might be shared with other apps or even other tenants (in a multi-tenant environment), running programs or scripts when something matches your URL.

Instead, your express instance is an http server all on its own.  It receives its own http requests, parses out the path of the resource being requested and the http verb being used and then checks that against your various Express-defined routes to see what matches so it can call the callbacks associated with those routes.

So, rather than the http server being a completely separate thing that runs on its own and may be configured to do many things on behalf of many separate apps, in nodejs, an http server is just a component that a server-based application can use.  In fact, it could have multiple http servers on different ports for different purposes all part of the same body of code.  For example, there could be the outward facing https server that fields incoming requests from customers on port 80 and there could be a separate http server on port 4000 (often called a control port) used for maintenance activities such as logging settings or load management, diagnostic activities such as accessing internally kept server statistics, etc...

Comment: Thanks. But, Java and Python have their own http module. Then why do they rely on Apache or CGI ?

Comment: @NikhileshAS - Java doesn't have to rely on CGI or Apache.  They just choose to support that as one possible deployment model.  Nodejs could be used that way too, but that is not what they chose to optimize for.  More likely, Nodejs fits into a multi-tenant structure by using a proxy like NGINX that distributes traffic to different web servers rather than using Apache or CGI.

Comment: @NikhileshAS - In higher scale deployments, one might use NGINX or some other proxy in front of nodejs for handling the serving of static resources, https endpoints, load balancing, URL redirection, some security barriers, etc... some of the things that Apache might have been useful for in other architectures.

Comment: @NikhileshAS - I also think Java grew up in an era where the http server was thought of as this major centralized thing that you hooked various applications onto. The initial architecture was thought to be an app server hooking into a separate http server. By the time nodejs came around, the world had advanced and it was acceptable that an http server could just be a component that you incorporate and build around in your own app. Also, long gone where the days where every incoming http request starts up a program from scratch to serve just that request (as in the original CGI architecture).

Comment: And I guess that was the reason why web pages were slower.

Comment: @NikhileshAS - Definitely one factor.  Of course, we now have tons faster server CPUs, faster routers, faster networks, faster backbones, faster browsers, etc... which also all contribute.  And, not to be discounted, developers can still make dog slow web pages today with all the junk they throw in them.  But, it is now possible to make some screaming fast web pages.

Comment: @NikhileshAS - Has this answered your question?

Comment: Yes. It has answered and it has widened my knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Express is nodejs framework. They both express and nodejs work for server side rendering. But expressjs is easy to use and user friendly. e.x:
in expressjs we write

```
   const express = require('express')
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) = {
res.send('Welcome to hompe page.')
})
app.listen(5500)
```

but in nodejs

```
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

And so many thing to do, you will find express is easy to use.